# Change remote HEAD branch in git hosted on visual studio online

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

When People clone this specific visual studio online repo, instead of getting the expected `master` branch, they're getting a branch called `initial`.

I would like the branch called `master` to be the default branch that gets checked-out when cloning the repository.

Indeed, when running `git branch -a` i'm getting the following result:

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/initial
remotes/origin/initial
remotes/origin/master
```

Which basically confirms that HEAD points to initial.

Also note that I do not have direct access to the remote file system (as it's hosted on visual studio online).

In github.com it's possible via the web portal, but I didn't find a similar option in visual studio online.

How can i change the remote repository to the following state?

```
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Web Access, navigate to the repository in question.  In the repository drop-down, select "Manage repositories...":

[image: Manage repositories]

On the left side of the repository management page, you can expand the repository to see the branches. Select the branch you want to make the default branch, right-click and select "Set as default branch".

[image: Set as default branch]

Comment: That option no longer exists. Any idea how to do it in the new GUI?

Comment: Hover over the settings cog -> Version Control -> click on your repo in the list on the left -> hover over your branch and click on the ellipsis (...) -> Set as default branch